# Windows service can not access the other projects in runtime

Tags: c#, windows-services, runtime

In my Solution Explorer i have many projects ( target framework 3.5) and one windows service (target framework 4.0)

in my windows service i used some methods form other projects

but in run time my service cannot access any of them

any idea ??

Comment: did you deploy the other dll with your service ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "my service cannot access any of them". Exception thrown or...?

Comment: "some methods form other projects"? You mean class libraries? If so, make sure the class library dll is available to the service.

Comment: @FelicePollano yes i put all of them in my service `BridgeWService\bin\Debug`

Comment: @ken2k No Exception but give me null for all property

Comment: Post the error - it'll help us help you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Visual Studio, correct? First, what kind of projects are your non-windows service projects in your solution (DLL, windows form, etc.)? If they are DLL project, make sure you have a reference to them in your Windows Service project. Also, ensure that all of your projects are using the same .NET Framework version, as that may cause issues.

When you say at runtime, do you mean when you have installed and run your service via the Services Manager? Or, are you just mocking the service for now and running it as a Console app? Are you getting an exception, or is the code not compiling?

Once I have some of these answers I can provide a better response. Thanks.